# MahApp.Metro configuration prob

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have just configured MahApp.Metro to my WPF form but after all configuration i got problems

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); << Red under line (does not exist in current context) >>
        }
    }
```

When i comment this section it run my application correctly but is it Good to comment this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using 2 diffrent namespaces/classnames in your .xaml and you .xaml.cs file.

If you have definded your x:Class (in the .xaml file of the form) as `x:Class=Your.Namespace.YourClass` the class of the .xaml file has to start with

```
namespace Your.Namespace {
    public partial class YourClass : MetroWindow {
        ...
```